# Application Failure Without Crash Log

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Having perused many other questions concerning unusual app crashes without any success at solving my problem, I have decided to post this question.

I have an app that crashes at random.  Some users (in test) never have crashes, others have an occasional crash.  This app is installed via XCode on testers phones, straight from the development machine.  The app never crashes when in use, only upon startup a day or two after installation and use.

The app is instrumented with Crashlytics, and no crashes are detected, nor are Out Of Memory warnings.  No crash logs are left on the phone after this behavior.

Crashlytics works.  I injected test crashes and they were properly detected.

Once the app crashes, it will not restart.  The splash screens appears for an instant and then the app closes.

The app uses Core Data and I use ObjectiveRecord https://github.com/supermarin/ObjectiveRecord as the Core Data interface.  There are no aborts anywhere in the code (at least none that I added/left in)

The app downloads about 1500 images (photographs) at initialization time, and whenever the photos collection is updated.  The filenames are stored in Core Data, not the binary data.

As an experiment, I took the container from the same app on another phone and replaced the container on the defective phone.  No difference.  Replacing the container on the good phone with the container from the bad phone made no difference either.

If I reinstall the app on the target phone, without deleting the original install, all works as expected.  This leads me to believe that I am not suffering from database corruption - obviously, I may be wrong, but if advice can be offered as to how to test this, I will happily accept it.

I am at my wits' end here - any advice as to what the problem might be, or how to diagnose the problem will be gratefully received.

EDIT -- The app is for IOS 9, iphone only.

Comment: What are the most common crash output logs (as you say it crashes randomly?) Could you post them? Are there any processes that are capable to cause certain unexpected issues?

Comment: There are none!  That's my biggest problem - silent crashes with no crash logs on the device, no crash notifications from Crashlytics, and no OOM warnings.

Comment: So when app is running while connected to XCode, is it always running properly?

Comment: Yes.  Never crashes in xcode.

Comment: Look into the device console log and check for entries appearing once that situation occurs.

Comment: iPhone amfid[2508] <Error>: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/25BE181B-C30F-41FF-87A3-88C8E63BB3B3/test.app/TEST not valid: 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
Aug 28 15:23:07 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:test.test.TEST[0x6c6e][2600]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Aug 28 15:23:07 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:test.test.TEST0x6c6e]' exited abnormally via signal.
Aug 28 15:23:07 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect OOM issues, even though I have no indication of them elsewhere,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall answer my own question.  I have been distributing the app to my 4 testers using a MacBook.  I only have one license, and rather than downloading it and moving it between my iMac and MacBook, I was just allowing Xcode to generate a new certificate.

This doesn't work.  Ever.

It invalidated all of the copies of the app that I installed.

The moral of the story is:  beware of licensing issues - even if you have a license.

and the hint was:

Aug 29 15:48:28 iPhone amfid[170] : /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/25BE181B-C30F-41FF-87A3-88C8E63BB3B3/TEST.app/TEST not valid: 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.

Live and learn I guess......